# Error while resolving type because of constructor?

Tags: singleton, unity-container, mvvm-light

I get an error:

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "MyAppApp.ServiceAgents.IMyAppServiceAgent", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type Int32 cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving MyAppApp.ServiceAgents.MyAppServiceAgent,(none) (mapped from MyAppApp.ServiceAgents.IMyAppServiceAgent, (none))
  Resolving parameter "AuthHandlerId" of constructor MyAppApp.ServiceAgents.MyAppServiceAgent(System.Int32 AuthHandlerId, System.String AuthSessionGuid, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress ServiceEndPointAddress)
    Resolving System.Int32,(none)
```

in the method which is below:

```
internal ServiceLocator()
        {
            services = new Dictionary<object, object>();
            // fill the map

            this.services.Add(typeof(IMyAppServiceAgent), _container.Resolve<IMyAppServiceAgent>());


        }
```

This is how I call this method

I have a standard method in the ViewModelLocator (from MVVM Light Toolkit) method

```
public static void CreateShowroomLog()
        {
            if (_showroomLog == null)
            {
                _showroomLog = new ShowroomLogViewModel(ServiceLocator.Instance(_container).GetService<IMyAppServiceAgent>());
            }
        }
```

and constructor is

```
 public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            _container=new UnityContainer();
            _container.RegisterType<IMyAppServiceAgent, MyAppServiceAgent>();
        }
```

The class of which I need an instance is:

```
protected static EndpointAddress ServiceEndPointAddress
        {
            get { return (App.Current as App).ServiceEndpointAddr; }

        }

        protected static string AuthSessionGuid
        {
            get { return (App.Current as App).W2OGuid; }
        }

        protected static int AuthHandlerId
        {
            get { return (App.Current as App).OriginalHandlerId; }
        }
public MyAppServiceAgent(int AuthHandlerId, string AuthSessionGuid, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress ServiceEndPointAddress)
        {
            _proxy = new MyAppService.Service1Client(new BasicHttpMessageInspectorBinding(new SilverlightAuthMessageInspector(AuthHandlerId.ToString(), AuthSessionGuid)), ServiceEndPointAddress);
        }

        public MyAppServiceAgent()
            : this(AuthHandlerId, AuthSessionGuid, ServiceEndPointAddress)
        {

        }
```

How can I resolve this problem with cosntructor?

Answer (score 1):

When you register your type you didn't specify which constructor to call on MyAppServiceAgent.  By default Unity will choose the constructor with the most parameters but you didn't specify how those parameters should be resolved.

You could try this and see if it will cause the the default constructor (paramaterless) of MyAppServiceAgent to be called when this type is resolved..

```
_container=new UnityContainer();
_container.RegisterType<IMyAppServiceAgent, MyAppServiceAgent>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

What I think would be even better is to remove the ServiceEndPointAddress, AuthSessionGuid and AuthHandlerId static properties from your MyAppServiceAgent class.  Then register the type like this

```
_container=new UnityContainer();
_container.RegisterType<IMyAppServiceAgent, MyAppServiceAgent>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        (App.Current as App).OriginalHandlerId,
        (App.Current as App).W2OGuid,
        (App.Current as App).ServiceEndpointAddr
    ));
```

Which should cause this constructor to be called.

```
public MyAppServiceAgent(int AuthHandlerId, string AuthSessionGuid, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress ServiceEndPointAddress)
    {
        _proxy = new MyAppService.Service1Client(new BasicHttpMessageInspectorBinding(new SilverlightAuthMessageInspector(AuthHandlerId.ToString(), AuthSessionGuid)), ServiceEndPointAddress);
    }
```

That way your MyAppServiceAgent class is not dependent on the App class.